# How much does a 400m time correlate to a good 5k race time prediction?

Tags: running, training, racing, 5k

The 400m distance is used to prepare for 5k races apparently, so can the times done in training be used to predict a 5k race time accurately?

If not then is racing a shorter distance the only way to predict a 5k time?

Actually this is the same as asking if there is a similar workout for 5k as the Yasso 800s workout for a marathon prediction time.

Comment: If you want a good workout for improving 5k times then amongst runners the current accepted progression can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3TYR3d9S1s1dFpwa3E4NmZfOW8/view

Comment: Also, Yasso 800s is just a fancy name on interval training, a well-understood method for improving times on faster races.

Comment: @JJosaur The Yasso workout is only for prediction purposes. I dont think anyone can expect to run a marathon with a training program that uses Yasso 800s as the main hard workout routine. After all predication methods shouldnt be too taxing anyways since they are just to help set paces for the real workouts. Thanks for the link Im checking it out.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't predict 5k race time from 400 meters timing, unless you decide to run at the same speed and are able to maintain it over the distance of 5k. You can sprint the whole of 400 meters, but for 5k you need strategy over pure speed. It requires stamina and periodic speeding and slowing down to have an edge over other participants when done at competitive level.

They are 2 different categories. To judge your 5k run's timing, you need to run 5k. Even if you run 1-2 k and record the timing, it may not give the accurate estimate for 5k either.

Comment: The workout called Yasso 800s works for marathons - maybe predicting a few minutes faster - so why not a workout for a 5k distance?

Comment: Preparing for marathon is different and estimating the time is. The best ever for 400 meters is around 45 seconds, if they run at that speed 5k would take them around 9 minutes to complete, while it takes 12-13 minutes to complete a 5k run for peak athletes.

Comment: The relationship your using is not what Im suggesting or what the Yasso 800s suggest either. For Yassos the average 800m time in mm:ss is the estimated marathon time in hh:mm, so a average 800m time of 3:10 gives an estimation of 3 hours and 10 mins but most people suggest to add 5-10 minutes onto this. Im going to figure it out then post it here when I do.

Comment: It's a theory, but how many put that into practice and for how many the results show as expected, I'm not sure. Marathon is a brilliant test of stamina, and 800 meters may indicate the time  as you have suggested, but not the capability of a person to get it done in that time. To gain the capability, experience in running marathon is required. If it works for you, that's great, but I'd never estimate my marathon timing from a shorter race based on any theory. There are chances I'd even fail to complete the race, but that's me.

Comment: I agree and dont mean to suggest that either. Its definitely not predicting capacity but since its not too stressing on the body then it doesn't mess up your marathon specific training. Its just a guide to help determine paces. For example, if it predicts a 3 hour 10 minutes marathon then you should figure out if that is too fast based on the training paces derived from it used to do the marathon training.

Comment: Hmm, sounds interesting and yes, marathons are quite stressful to train for. I wish you the best and let us know how it goes.

Comment: @Jason - I think the use of 400s or 800s is more to improve general "kick" performance, not for overall fitness and pacing as it applies to the longer distance races though, right?

Comment: @AndrewMattson Yeah I think, but in my question Im asking about using a workout to predict a 5k which is not as different as 800s and a marathon. Since the 5k and 400s are not as far apart then it might do both predict a time and improve 5k fitness.

Comment: It seems like the 800 is definitely where you see more of the transition away from the more muscular "speed" builds to the distance runner body types, so while the 400 to 5K may seem more similar, I think the running styles and how they impact the body are more similar between the 800 and further distances.

Comment: @AndrewMattson That is interesting and for me 800s really do feel different from 400s. Perhaps 800s are the thing to use for 5k too...